# By how much assignment is slower/faster than indexation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization, memory-access

When does redeclaring a new variable faster than accessing an item in a list repeatedly in python?

for example with this list -

```py
import time

fruits = ["orange", "banana", "strawberry", "apple"]
```

when running this code

```py
timesToRun = 1000000
timesToAccess = 100

start_time = time.time()
for x in range(timesToRun):
    for y in range(timesToAccess):
        tempFruit = fruits[2] # Accessing the list directly
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))


start_time = time.time()
for x in range(timesToRun):
    myFruit = fruits[2] # Declaring a new variable
    for y in range(timesToAccess):
        tempFruit = myFruit # Accessing the variable
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And I got the following print -

```
--- 5.268802165985107 seconds ---
--- 4.507154226303101 seconds ---
```

so clearly redeclaring the item is faster than accessing it 100 times,

but when I am only accessing the item once

```py
timesToRun = 10000000
timesToAccess = 1
```

the print is

```
--- 1.948554277420044 seconds ---
--- 2.1312568187713623 seconds ---
```

so now it is faster to just access it directly.

So my question is what is the threshold, when is it better to redeclare the item than access it directly? and with a dictionary or NumPy arrays is it any different answer?

EDIT:
I guess my question can also be by how much does declaring a new variable is slower then just accessing a list.

Comment: You can find out the threshold yourself by changing `timesToAccess`.

Comment: The difference is rarely significant in context.  It's almost always beneficial to move repeated computations out of a loop, but there's not going to be a general rule.

Comment: because `fruits[2]` is an operation which takes time, essentially, it is a method call to the `list` object, but first, it is a global lookup to `fruits` to find the list.  `myFruit` is just a global lookup

Comment: @TimRoberts I am not looking for an answer for this specific block of code I am looking for a general idea when is it better to do which of the ways

Comment: when you **don't want to repeat an operation every iteration because it takes significant time or adds to your algorithmic complexity**. And example of the latter, consider something like using `max_num = max(fruits)`. If you use the variable outside the loop, you are finding the max **once**. In the loop, you are finding the max (which isn't changing) *once per iteration*

Comment: Where in my answer did you see anything specific to this block of code?  I was speaking in generalities.  Python is somewhat limited in detecting common subexpressions.  That means you just have to use your intuition.  However, don't fall into the trap of "premature optimization".  Don't waste time optimizing code until you know it is a problem.

Comment: Note that you are not "redeclaring" anything here. It is just an affectation of an existing variable. Except for the first time, which, somehow, declare it (there is not really any such thing as "declaring a variable" here; but you can consider the 1st affectation as taking place of declaration).

Comment: So what you have here, is that timeToAccess+1 assignments plus 1 indexation, is cheaper than timeToAccess assignment plus timeToAccess indexation. That is that 1 assignment is cheaper than timeToAccess-1 indexation. Which is not really surprising. Unless timeToAccess is 1, in which case indeed, 1 assignment is not cheaper than 0 indexation... not surprising neither

Comment: Relevant: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](//nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: For your edit: almost so, yes. Your question is "how much assignment is slower/faster than indexation". Again, no "declaring" here. You were already doing timeToAccess assignments in your first version (for each of the timeToRun loop, and ignoring the assignments of `y` that are in both version anyway). All what you added in the second version is 1 single assignment. 2nd version does timeToAccess+1 assignments where the 1st is doing "only" timeToAccess. And in exchange it has to do only 1 indexation, where the 1st had to do timeToAccess indexation.